# Allow user to manage mail templates

Tags: permissions, message-templates

I can't find out how to allow a CiviCRM user to manage the mail templates, i.e access

/civicrm/admin/messageTemplates

...without giving the "Administer CiviCRM" permission. How can I do that ?

I'm using Drupal 7 and CiviCRM 4.5.8.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"edit message templates" is a separate permission in CiviCRM 4.6 (see screenshot below), so you'll get this functionality by upgrading.

Upgrading is also a good idea, since version 4.5 isn't a "Long Term Support" version of CiviCRM and thus doesn't receive security updates.

[image]

Comment: I upgraded to 4.6.9, but I can't find a "Administer Mail Templates" line in the Drupal permissions page (/admin/people/permissions), is it located elsewhere ? Thanks

Comment: @Flo - it's there - but it's called "CiviCRM: edit message templates".  I'll update my answer plus add a screenshot.